# How to evaluate the path to a python script to be executed within Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Note: I am not simply asking how to execute a Python script within Jupyter, but how to evaluate a python variable which would then result in the full path of the Python script I was to execute.

In my particular scenario, some previous cell on my notebook generates a path based on some condition.

Example on two possible cases:

1. `script_path = /project_A/load.py`
2. `script_path = /project_B/load.py`

Then some time later, I have a cell where I just want to execute the script. Usually, I would just do:
`%run -i /project_A/load.py`

but I want to keep the cell's code generic by doing something like:

`%run -i script_path`

where `script_path` is a Python variable whose value is based on the conditions that are evaluated earlier in my Jupyter notebook.

The above would not work because Jupyter would then complain that it cannot find `script_path.py`.

Any clues how I can have a Python variable passed to the `%run` magic?

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way would be to change the directory via `%cd path`

and then run the script with `%run -i file.py`

E: I know that this is not exactly what you were asking but maybe it helps with your problem.

Comment: I appreciate the hacky response, but indeed, it's not the best way to resolve the problem. But it's the best response so far though, considering you are the only one :)